# JDBC + JSF, getting error: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am getting this error: `Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).`

Here is my code:

```
Connection con = getConnection();
        String query = "select * from game_match where year = ? and (country_1 = '?' OR country_2 = '?')";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setInt(1, year);
        stmt.setString(2, country.getName());
        stmt.setString(3, country.getName());
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ...
```

I am using JDBC with JSF just for reference and it may have something do with my bean sessions in JSF.

Here is the full stack trace if needed:

```
May 08, 2016 3:01:29 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{matchData.getCountryMatchInfo(country, worldCupData.worldCup.year)}: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
javax.faces.FacesException: #{matchData.getCountryMatchInfo(country, worldCupData.worldCup.year)}: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3245)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3229)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:3996)
    at beans.MatchData.getCountryMatchInfo(MatchData.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more

May 08, 2016 3:01:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/fifa] threw exception [java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:695)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3245)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3229)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:3996)
    at beans.MatchData.getCountryMatchInfo(MatchData.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

The country parameters are not recognized as parameters since you have put them into string quotes. Just write

```
String query = 
   "select * from game_match where year = ? and (country_1 = ? OR country_2 = ?)";
```

Comment: good catch, didn't think it'd make a difference

Comment: Of course it makes a difference. `'?'` is a string literal that happens to contain a question mark. `?` is a JDBC parameter marker. *Big* difference.